# How do I fix "Missing \cr inserted" error produced when savetrees is used with IEEEtran?

Tags: ieeetran, savetrees

Here is an MWE that produces "Missing \cr inserted" error when `savetrees` is used with `IEEEtran`. When `savetrees` is removed, the error goes away. Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{Authors}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
My Introduction

\end{document}
```

Comment: just don't use savetrees is the canonical answer, the aims seem mutually incompatible, IEEEtran is trying to enforce the house style of IEEE journals and savetrees is trying to change the style

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation here must be not to use `savetrees` as the only reason to use a Journal supplied class such as IEEEtrans is to enforce the journal house style and the intention of the `savetrees` package is explicitly to change the layout and styling to use a more compact form so by design it is working against the intention of the class file.

That said if you use the `title` option it uses a different redefinition of the title layout which seems to avoid an error here.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[subtle,title]{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{Authors}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
My Introduction

\end{document}
```

[image]